# How to plot a stabilization diagram?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Let's say we have a list which contains another lists with some data, in my case frequencies.

```
model_order = [[], 
               [1], 
               [1.1], 
               [1, 1.5], 
               [1, 1.55, 3.5], 
               [1.1, 1.45, 3.45, 3.5, 4.8]]
```

As you can see, a nested lists have different length and can be empty as well.

I want to plot a diagram like [on the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMZQU.png),

[image]

but stuck on how to do it using python and matplotlib. How can I do it?

My first idea was to use a pyplot.plot() for several times and put model_order[i] as data for y-axis and np.linspace(1, len(model_order[i]), len(model_order[i])) as data for x-axis. But for that necessary to have x and y data with same first dimension.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy as np

def plot_stabilization_diagram(data):

    pyplot.figure(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=80)
    pyplot.subplot(1, 1, 1)

    yaxis = np.linspace(1, len(data), len(data))

    for d in xrange(len(data)):
        pyplot.plot(data[d], yaxis, 'o')

    pyplot.show()


>>> ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?  This reads as 'please do my work for me' which tends to annoy people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an array of the same order as model_order - to do this create an array with np.ones_like, np.zeros_like - you can then put whatever values you want into this array by iterating through it. You then need to iterate through each array within the array input to get each item to plot.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy as np

def plot_stabilization_diagram(data):

    pyplot.figure(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=80)
    pyplot.subplot(1, 1, 1)

    yaxis = np.ones_like(data)

    for pos, row in enumerate(data):
        for pos2, item in enumerate(row):
            pyplot.plot(item, yaxis[pos2], 'o')

    pyplot.show()

def plot_stabilization_diagram_2(data):

    pyplot.figure(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=80)
    pyplot.subplot(1, 1, 1)

    for pos, row in enumerate(data):
        for pos2, item in enumerate(row):
            pyplot.plot(pos, item, 'o')

    pyplot.show()

model_order = [[], 
           [1], 
           [1.1], 
           [1, 1.5], 
           [1, 1.55, 3.5], 
           [1.1, 1.45, 3.45, 3.5, 4.8]]

plot_stabilization_diagram(model_order)
```

Your code also puts all the frequencies from model_order onto the x-axis, rather than the y-axis.

The second version plots the frequencies based on their row number - more like what is in your example image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJwyr.jpg